CFBundleIdentifier Error: More than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value?
I am having an issue with CFBundleIdentifier error when trying to upload app ipa file to App Store Connect from Transport App.
I get the following error in Transporter app when trying to deliver the .ipa file to app store connect:
Asset validation failed (90685)
CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 
'com.jordanjcastro8.castroCookbook' under the iOS application 'Runner.app'. 
(ID: 9b205294-8d8b-4d4a-a7ef-74b559054ed8)

I have already read through the solutions of similar posts online such as:

click runner in xcode -> general tab -> under frameworks, libraries, and embedded content set Pods_Runner.framework to 'do not embed', and
click build phases tab -> delete embed pods frameworks step.

I tried these solutions but when I run 'flutter build ipa' it builds archive and ipa with no issue but I notice while this is running I checked xcode and saw Runner tab closes so I opened it and clicked to build phases tab and saw that the embed pods frameworks step has reappeared and is probably being applied in the 'flutter build ipa' command.
I suspect this reappearance of the embed pods frameworks step is why I continue to get the CFBundleIdentifier error in Transport.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? Is there a script I could use and where would I put this script to have it run?

Same issue, in my case, I had to revert the CFBundleIdentifier in the AppFrameworkInfo.plist.

I thought it was the bundle ID of the application, but it wasn’t.
So, DO NOT edit AppFrameworkInfo.plist file.
